Destructuring in a Ruby block when using index
Without using index I was able to destructure the first and second elements of an Array of Arrays like so:
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ] ].each do |first, second|
  puts second
end
#=> 2
#=> 4

I then needed to get the index for each iteration so I used .with_index and I assumed the index would just get added as the last argument of the block:
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ] ].each.with_index do |first, second, index|
  puts second
end
#=> 0
#=> 1

However, it was the index. The first value is the entire Array, not destructured.
How do you use .with_index and still destructure the Array?

Ruby uses the phrases "decompose" and "decomposition". This is a documented feature and has been discussed quite a few times on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53999977/1978251,https://stackoverflow.com/q/64247473/1978251, https://stackoverflow.com/q/55561826/1978251, https://stackoverflow.com/q/31772441/1978251

@engineersmnky Appreciate that. I did a bunch of searches prior to this but without knowing the "decompose"/"decomposition" keyword, I didn't get great results. I always like sharing back knowledge to save the next soul so hopefully this does just that.

You can destructure by passing parentheses to the first argument and that will destructure as before and keep the index as the second argument:
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 3, 4 ] ].each.with_index do |( first, second ), index|
  puts second
end
#=> 2
#=> 4


Just as (first, second), idx = [[[1,2], [3,4]], 2] produces first #=> [1,2], second #=> [3,4], idx #=> 2. See the doc for Array Decomposition.
